# Processing json array in PHP sent via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to consume a JSON array in PHP sent via JQuery. The data being sent to the server is in this format:

```
[{"id":"7","start":"00:00","end":"02:30","date":"2013-11-15"},{"id":"10","start":"23:00","end":"23:30","date":"2013-11-15"},{"id":"5","start":"13:00","end":"14:00","date":"2013-11-16"},{"id":"6","start":"18:00","end":"18:45","date":"2013-11-16"}]
```

I am sending the above data to the server through this function:

```
$('#updateOverallChanges').click(function(event){
            var formArray = new Array();
            $('.updateForm').each(function( index ) {
                formArray.push($(this).JSONFromSerialize());
            });


            $.ajax({
                url: 'inner/formTester.php',
                data: JSON.stringify(formArray),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            });
        });
```

The function `JSONFromSerialize` is responsible for converting the form in meaningful json data:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.JSONFromSerialize = function() {

        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [ o[this.name] ];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I am using the following PHP code to process the JSON array:

```
<?php
$params = json_decode($_POST[]);
echo $params;
?>
```

But the above code give the following output:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\xampp\htdocs\holidaymanager\inner\formTester.php on line 2
```

---

**Second attempt**

Modified the payload to be a name value pair:

```
 var postData = {
                data : formArray
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: 'inner/formTester.php',
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            });
```

The post data is:

```
{"data":[{"id":"7","start":"00:00","end":"02:30","date":"2013-11-15"},{"id":"10","start":"23:00","end":"23:30","date":"2013-11-15"},{"id":"5","start":"13:00","end":"14:00","date":"2013-11-16"},{"id":"6","start":"18:00","end":"18:45","date":"2013-11-16"}]}
```

The php code still fails:

```
<?php
$params = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
echo $params;

?>
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\holidaymanager\inner\formTester.php on line 2
```

Please advice how can I consume a JSON array sent over to the backend written in PHP.

Comment: Have you tried `json_decode($_POST)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $.ajax({
            data : {data:JSON.stringify(postData)},
   })
```

**in php**

```
  $params = $_POST['data']; // add this line 
  $params = json_decode($params,true); 
  print_r($params);
```

**or else**

```
  $params = json_decode($_POST,true);
  print_r($params);
```

you have pass 2nd argument **true** with json_Decode()...

hope it may help you

Comment: I am getting this message: `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\holidaymanager\inner\formTester.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />`

Comment: the ajax request is sent like this: `$.ajax({
                url: 'inner/formTester.php',
                data : {'data':JSON.stringify(formArray)},
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            });`

Comment: change 'data' to data

Comment: getting the same warning message

Comment: the payload seems to be messed up: `data=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A%225%22%2C%22start%22%3A%2213%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2214%3A00%22%2C%22date%22%3A%222013-11-16%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%226%22%2C%22start%22%3A%2218%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2218%3A45%22%2C%22date%22%3A%222013-11-16%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%221%22%2C%22start%22%3A%2203%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2204%3A00%22%2C%22date%22%3A%222013-11-17%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%222%22%2C%22start%22%3A%2212%3A00%22%2C%22end%22%3A%2212%3A30%22%2C%22date%22%3A%222013-11-17%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%223%22%2C%22start%22%3A%2216%3A15%22%2C%22end%22%3A%...`

Comment: yup...that did it... :D